# Loop into an index and then print the result into Excel

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, python-requests

I have this code below (this is part of my code, that I am using request into an API url):

```
name = []
subTask = [] 

#results in excel
for i in range(len(nome)):
    sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=2).value = name[i]
    sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=8).value = subTask[i]

#Loop into the API DATA
for i in data['data']:
    name.append(i['name'])
    if i['subTask']:
      
      subTask.append(i['subTask'][0]['name']) 
     
    else:
      subTask.append('')
```

What I'm trying to do: This subTasks have more than one name, and with my index [0] I'm only printing the first name that appears for every I

How can I get the result about every subTask? I tried:

```
for i in data['data']:
    name.append(i['name'])
    if i['subTask']:
      startIndex = 0
      subTask.append(i['subTask'][startIndex]['name']) 
      print(subTask)
      startIndex += 1
    else:
      subTask.append('')
```

Maybe I need to change my line who prints the value in Excel too:

```
sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=8).value = subTask[i]
```

Example :

I have one subTask that have 2 names below:
Send Email
Check Email

My code now only prints the first one (Send Email) into excel, the output that i need is to print both of them (Send Email Check Email)

My output can be at the same cell into excel, or into another cell works fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expected *behaviour/output* is not fully clear, so I imagine you want something like below :

```
data = {
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "T1",
            "subTask": [
                {"name": "Send Email"},
                {"name": "Check Email"}
            ]
        }
    ]
} # A mockup of the API response (to be confirmed!)
    
name, subTask = [], []

for d in data["data"]:
    name.append(d["name"])
    
    subTask.append(
        "/".join( # <- change the separator if needed
            [sub["name"] for sub in d["subTask"]] # <- querying the subTasks
        )
    )

for i, (n, st) in enumerate(zip(name, subTask), start=1):
    sheet.cell(row=i, column=2).value = n
    sheet.cell(row=i, column=8).value = st

workbook.save("output.xlsx") # <- to be adjusted
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: It workeeeeed. Thanks 

Can u explain better this part of the code ? 

 [sub["name"] for sub in d.get("subTask", [])]
        ) 

i didnt get well why sub['name] and the loop into the same line

Comment: You're welcome ;) I simplified it to `[sub["name"] for sub in d["subTask"]]` (*check the [update](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76510035/2)*). Since the subtasks info are held in a list of dicts `[{"name": "Send Email"}, {"name": "Check Email"}]`, we use a [*listcomp*](https://peps.python.org/pep-0202/) to query all the names and then `"/".join` them to make a classical list `['Send Email/Check Email']` that will be used later to update the Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Thankssss, now its clear.  I appreciate your help